# Create drop-down menus dynamically using a json data file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, drop-down-menu

I am on process of creating an web application which has a Hierarchy panel, where I facilitate user to drill down up-to a certain extent using drop-down menus. I use a `JSON` file to create all these select menus and their options.

The drop-down menus that I want to create as follow.

- Delivery Center
- Program
- Account
- Project
- ERP

How can I generate all the drop-down menus including it's data. Please tell me an optimal way to resolve this matter. jQuery or JavaScript preferred.

[You can find the `JSON` file with the message in this document.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx37qvKU4PoUVEdzZnBES2p2aUU/edit?usp=sharing)

Following is the way I was trying to do it. But to create each and every menu i need to write a separate function.

```
//load the json Files in the page load
$("#mobile-page").on("pageinit", function () {
  $.getJSON("assets/json/HierarchyDef.json", function (hJson) {
    for (var index in hJson) {
      if (hJson.hasOwnProperty(index)) {
        $("#selectmenu0").append('<option  value="' + hJson[index].definitionID + '"> ' + hJson[index].definitionName + '</option>');
      }
    }
  });
  $("#selectmenu0").selectmenu('refresh');
  createMenus();
});

function createMenus() {
  $.getJSON("assets/json/OrganizationalHierarchy.json", function (treeJson) {
    var hindex = 0;
    deliveryCenter(treeJson, hindex);
    program(treeJson, hindex);
  });
}

function deliveryCenter(treeJson, hindex) {
  var y = treeJson.levelChildren[hindex].levelType;
  var x = treeJson.levelChildren[hindex];
  alert(treeJson.levelChildren.length);
  dropdownlist = "<label for='selectmenu1' data-mini='true'> " + y + " </label>";
  dropdownlist += "<div data-role='fieldcontain'>";
  dropdownlist += "<select data-native-menu='true' onChange='detect(" + i + ")' name='selectmenu1' id='selectmenu1' data-mini='true'>";
  dropdownlist += "</select>";
  dropdownlist += "</div>";

  $("#dmenu").html(dropdownlist);
  $('#dmenu').trigger('create');
  for (i = 0; i < treeJson.levelChildren.length; i++) {
    $("#selectmenu1").append('<option  value="' + treeJson.levelChildren[i].levelName + '"> ' + treeJson.levelChildren[i].levelName + '</option>');
  }
}

function program(treeJson, hindex) {
  var y = treeJson.levelChildren[hindex].levelChildren[hindex].levelType;
  var x = treeJson.levelChildren[hindex];
  alert(treeJson.levelChildren[hindex].levelChildren.length);
  dropdownlist = "<label for='selectmenu2' data-mini='true'> " + y + " </label>";
  dropdownlist += "<div data-role='fieldcontain'>";
  dropdownlist += "<select data-native-menu='true' onChange='detect(" + i + ")' name='selectmenu2' id='selectmenu2' data-mini='true'>";
  dropdownlist += "</select>";
  dropdownlist += "</div>";

  $("#dmenu2").html(dropdownlist);
  $('#dmenu2').trigger('create');
  for (i = 0; i < treeJson.levelChildren.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < treeJson.levelChildren[i].levelChildren.length; j++) {
      alert(j);
      $("#selectmenu2").append('<option  value="' + treeJson.levelChildren[i].levelChildren[j].levelName + '"> ' + treeJson.levelChildren[i].levelChildren[j].levelName + '</option>');
    }
  }
}
```

JSON File used.... i have attached the json file in the above link

```
{
  "levelType":"Root",
  "levelId":null,
  "levelName":"RootElement",
  "levelChildren":[
    {
      "levelType":"Delivery Center ",
      "levelId":null,
      "levelName":"CLR",
      "levelChildren":[
        {
          "levelType":"Program",
          "levelId":null,
          "levelName":"Europe",
          "levelChildren":[
            {
              "levelType":"Account",
              "levelId":null,
              "levelName":"BaC",
              "levelChildren":[
                {
                  "levelType":"Project",
                  "levelId":null,
                  "levelName":"BTR200",
                  "levelChildren":[
                    {
                      "levelType":"ERP",
                      "levelId":null,
                      "levelName":"BTWLM00",
                      "levelChildren":[
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"9779",
                          "levelName":"bbapdler                                                                                ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"9780",
                          "levelName":"cmnlib                                                                                              ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "levelType":"Project",
                  "levelId":null,
                  "levelName":"B190",
                  "levelChildren":[
                    {
                      "levelType":"ERP",
                      "levelId":null,
                      "levelName":"B190",
                      "levelChildren":[
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"9875",
                          "levelName":"bgging                                                                                       ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"9876",
                          "levelName":"rbmaient                                                                                   ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"9877",
                          "levelName":"seril                                                                                 ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "levelType":"Delivery Center ",
      "levelId":null,
      "levelName":"CHE",
      "levelChildren":[ 
        {
          "levelType":"Program",
          "levelId":null,
          "levelName":"DivV",
          "levelChildren":[
            {
              "levelType":"Account",
              "levelId":null,
              "levelName":"Synted",
              "levelChildren":[
                {
                  "levelType":"Project",
                  "levelId":null,
                  "levelName":"Synce",
                  "levelChildren":[
                    {
                      "levelType":"ERP",
                      "levelId":null,
                      "levelName":"Syenance",
                      "levelChildren":[
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"10104",
                          "levelName":"JCCommon                                                                                            ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"10105",
                          "levelName":"JCDriver                                                                                            ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"10106",
                          "levelName":"JCManager                                                                                           ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "levelType":"Program",
          "levelId":null,
          "levelName":"MHices",
          "levelChildren":[
            {
              "levelType":"Account",
              "levelId":null,
              "levelName":"Meve",
              "levelChildren":[
                {
                  "levelType":"Project",
                  "levelId":null,
                  "levelName":"Mckntive",
                  "levelChildren":[
                    {
                      "levelType":"ERP",
                      "levelId":null,
                      "levelName":"Mcntive",
                      "levelChildren":[
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"3912",
                          "levelName":"Logiwork                                                                                      ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        },
                        {
                          "levelType":"ModuleName",
                          "levelId":"3913",
                          "levelName":"Registry                                                                                            ",
                          "levelChildren":[

                          ]
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: using mustache or handlebars is a lot cleaner than writing DOM code or string HTML.

Comment: I think the first step is reorganizing JSON data.

Comment: I am trying to finish my solution. When I finish I'll post it.

Comment: Thanks alot Victor ,, appreciate your effort,:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the JSON data it's impossible to write an exact script but step 1 would be, if you control the JSON data, to organize it in the best way possible. Such as:

```
Object ->
    Menu 1 ->
        Item 1 -> data
        Item 3 -> data
    Menu 2 ->
        Item 1 -> data
        Item 2 -> data
        Item 3 -> data
```

Then when looping your data to build the menu you would basically do:

```
Loop Over JSON data {
    html += '<ul>';
    Loop Over Menu Items {
        html += '<li>';
        html += //OTHER HTML
        html += '</li>';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
}
```

I hope you get the conecept.

Comment: I want to create 5 different Drop-down menus
-Delivery Center
-Program
-Account
-Project
-ERP

Comment: i have use 5 functions to do this, but i know that is not the better way to do it, please suggest me an optimal way to do this.

Comment: I would organize the JSON data as shown in my first code block. Organize it by menu, then you can use one function to loop over the JSON data, by menu.